# How to find /etc/apt/sources.conf file

Tags: 16.04

I am wondering how to find the `/etc/apt/sources.conf file`in Ubuntu 16.04.4 terminal ? It should contains URLs to archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Are you sure the file you are looking for is not `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Maybe you should ask about whatever it is that you are trying to do with this file. If you make changes to it and you don't know what you're doing, you can easily break your system

Answer (score 1):

The file is just `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  The `file` part is just referring to the file that it just mentions, which is `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Hi, yes I have found `/etc/apt/sources.list` but how to open the file ?

Comment: @engr_john you open it with a text editor - command line editors like `nano` or `vi` exist, or you can try to use a GUI editor with `pkexec gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` to try and access it with the GUI (though it is advised to use the CLI editors instead so that file permissions for the GUI configuraiton bits don't get messed up from a permissions point of view)

Comment: Another way to open it with a GUI editor is `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` if you want to edit it. If you want to simply read it, remove the `sudo -H` part.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to do this is by traversing the directory structure. To move up a level in the directory, it's `../`.

You want to go all the way to the filesystem root to get to /etc. So, that's up two levels of directories - assuming you started in your /home/user directory.

So, let's say I want to edit the file you probably meant to mention - `sources.list`. My command would look like:

```
sudo nano ../../etc/apt/sources.list
```

The sudo is, of course, to elevate my permissions. The 'nano' is a text editor that you can use in the terminal - and it's easy to learn to use. Then, the following is the path to the file.

As you see in the path, I went up two levels, each with a `../`. That takes me to the filesystems root (not to be confused with root user) which is just plain `/`. Once it takes me there, it then digs down into the directories and opens the file in question.

If, for some reason, you were in your Downloads folder (under your /home/user directory) then it'd be:

```
sudo nano ../../../etc/apt/sources.list
```

It's pretty easy this way, so long as you know where you are in the directory structure.